# Oracle - how to reference to a field%TYPE using database links?

Tags: oracle, datatypes, database-link

I have this database which includes a couple of schemas. Say I need to access schemaONE from schemaTWO. To do this, I have created a database link named "DB_ONE_LINK".

I am able to access to schemaONE's tables using the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM "Tbl1"@"DB_ONE_LINK";
```

Now, when creating SPs and functions in schemaONE, I can define variables like this:

```
tmp_amount "schemaONE"."Tbl1"."Amount"%TYPE;
```

The question is, how can I reference to a field type in schemaONE using "DB_ONE_LINK"?
something like this:

```
tmp_amount "Tbl1"."Amount"@"DB_ONE_LINK"%TYPE;
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Firstly, do you understand that you don't actually need to use a database link to access other schemas in the same database? Database links are used to access other databases. (See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37012/difference-between-database-vs-user-vs-schema )

Comment: @Phil: Thank you for your reply, well I know that I can grant select to the other user in the same database and resolve this issue for now, but we might wanna split these schemas to different databases. what if then?

Comment: As far as I can see, you're going to have to define the type locally. Could be wrong, but I can't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** reference a remote table in a procedure or a package. Here's an example with a loopback link:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l dual.dummy@loopback%TYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT * INTO l FROM dual@loopback;
  5     dbms_output.put_line(l);
  6  END;
  7  /

X

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

I think there are restrictions and you should probably use a workaround such as a local view that references the remote table or a local synonym.

In any case this should remain an exception, obviously the best place to store a procedure is in the database where the data is stored. If you find that a program frequently needs access to several databases, it might be a good idea to merge those databases.

Comment: Now, I thought that he wanted to use `%TYPE` against a user-defined type that didn't exist on the local database. Must have read into the question too much.